# Footer toggle with changing image

Tags: jquery, footer, slide

Thank you for giving me the opportunity to be helped.

I would like to create a toggle footer (slide pannel).

I found the code below which works fine but I want to be able to change the image when the pannel is slided: the image is different for opening and closing (arrow up --> arrow down).

How should I proceed to integrate this function with this code?

Many thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var slide = false;
var height = $('#footer_content').height();
$('#footer_button').click(function() {
var docHeight = $(document).height();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var scrollPos = docHeight - windowHeight + height;
$('#footer_content').animate({ height: "toggle"}, 1000);
if(slide == false) {
    if($.browser.opera) { //Fix opera double scroll bug by targeting only HTML.
        $('html').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
    }
                       slide = true;
} else {
                       slide = false;
               }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change an image by changing the image source:

```
$('.classOfImage').attr('src','/images/up.png');
```

Your image must have the class you use here `$('.classOfImage')`

```
<img src="/images/firstimage.pmg" alt="My Image" class="classOfImage" />
```

You may do something like this to integrate it in you current code:

```
var panel = false;
```

Define this variable outside your click function and set in to false.

Now add this to you click function:

```
if(!panel){
    $('.classOfImage').attr('src','/images/secondimage.png');
    panel = true;
} else if(panel) {
    $('.classOfImage').attr('src','/images/firstimage.png');
    panel = false;
}
```

As I could see you already have a variable that saves the panel status like this, called `slide` so you could use it like this:

```
$(function() {
    var slide = false;
    var height = $('#footer_content').height();

    $('#footer_button').click(function() {

    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollPos = docHeight - windowHeight + height;

    $('#footer_content').animate({ height: "toggle"}, 1000);

    if(!slide) {

        $('.classOfImage').attr('src','/images/secondimage.png'); // LOOK HERE !!

        if($.browser.opera) {
            $('html').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
        }
            slide = true;

    } else {

        $('.classOfImage').attr('src','/images/firstimage.png'); // AND HERE !!

           slide = false;
    }

    });
});
```

**Note:** `jQuery(function($) {` is the same as `$(function() {` and `if(slide == false)` is the same as `if(!slide)`

Comment: Thank you so much, Fabian. Unfortunately, this code don't work for me. The image changes but only when I click a second time. And I would like that the image changes automaticaliy when the toggle slides the pannel (without any click). Do you have a solution for me? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by without any click? I'll get back to you in a few minutes and will post a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: I think your panel is open by default, right? So you have to change `var slide = false;` to `var slide = true;`. Here is a jsfiddle for you to understand how it works. (Instead of changing a text like I did, you can change the image) http://jsfiddle.net/LHhQu/. Please upvote/accept if I could help you, or get back to me if you have further questions:)

Comment: Dear Fabian, you rock! It works like a charme now for me! My mistake was the following: I had inverted the first and second image in the code. Thank you so much for your kindness and patience!